# Send multiple csv attachments, simple Bash errors?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to Bash scripting and am trying to modify some code that I picked up from the net. Basically I'm trying to attach multiple files to the same email.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    function get_mimetype(){
    file --mime-type "$1" | sed 's/.*: //'
    }
    declare -a attachments
    attachments=("A_PTDIFF.CVS" "A_PTMISS.CVS" "A_PTNPOS.CVS" "A_PTRCON.CVS" 
    )

    # Build headers
    {

     printf '%s\n'"From: jrpng
     To: tom@gmail.com
     Subject: Test new Bash script
     Mime-Version: 1.0
     Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"=== Boundary ===\"
     --${=== Boundary ===}
     Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"US-ASCII\"
     Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
     Content-Disposition: inline
     The reports are attached to this email as requested
     "
     for file in "${attachments[@]}"; do
     [ ! -f "$file" ] && echo "Attachment $file not found, omitting file" 
     >&2 && continue
     mimetype=$(get_mimetype "$file")
     printf '%s\n' "--${=== Boundary ===}
     Content-Type: $mimetype
     Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
     Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"
     "
     base64 "$file"
     echo
     done
     # print last boundary with closing --
     printf '%s\n' "--${=== Boundary ===}--"
     } | /usr/lib/sendmail -t -oi
```

Okay when run via bash sendmail54.sh I get the following

```
    sendmail54.sh: line 22: From: jrpng
    To: tom@gmail.com
    Subject: Test new Bash script
    `Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=== Boundary ==="
    --${=== Boundary ===}
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset="US-ASCII"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Content-Disposition: inline
    The reports are attached to this email as requested
    : bad substitution
    No recipient addresses found in header
```

No idea what the error message is telling me?

If there is a better approach to what I am trying to achieve I'm more than happy to try that, as stated new to bash scripting so am fumbling around in the dark trying to get this working.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "--${=== Boundary ===}--"` => `printf '%s\n' "--\${=== Boundary ===}--"`  Note the `\$`, you will probably also need `printf --  '%s\n' "--\${=== Boundary ===}--"` and `"--\${=== Boundary ===}--"` at line 22.

Comment: How should your output look like?

Comment: You should also use a *heredoc* for the block of text and single-quote the sigil to prevent variable expansion, e.g. `cat << 'EOF' (long block for header) EOF` where there is a newline after the first `EOF` and before the last. The `printf `'%s\n'` is a shady way to handle that.

Comment: Hesitantly upvoting for correctly using double quotes around all the other variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of basic syntax errors and misunderstandings.

Apparently the original code had a variable `boundary="randomstring"` and then interpolated that at the right places with `--${boundary}`.  But you attempt to use the *boundary string itself* inside `${...}` which is just nonsense -- what goes between the braces is the name of a variable.

Also, your mail message needs some empty lines in order to be valid. The general structure is

```
From: whoever
To: wherever
Subject: whatever
Mime-version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart something something; boundary="randomstring"

<- empty line between message headers and first body part

--randomstring
Content-type: of first attachment
x-headers: and etc

<- empty line before here; now the actual attachment data

--randomstring
Content-type: of second attachment
x-headers: and etc

payload of second attachment goes here, again after an empty line

--randomstring--
```

Piecing together an email message by hand requires you to understand MIME which most people simply don't want to.  If you have a sensible mail program like `mutt` installed, you don't need to understand the details of how exactly to format an SMTP MIME message correctly.

Anyway, here is an attempt at fixing your current code, with comments, and proper indentation.

```
function get_mimetype(){
  file --mime-type "$1" | sed 's/.*: //'
}
declare -a attachments
attachments=("A_PTDIFF.CVS" "A_PTMISS.CVS" "A_PTNPOS.CVS" "A_PTRCON.CVS")

{
  boundary="--random$$string--"
  # You were missing a space after '%s\n'
  # Also, I'm breaking this into multiple arguments for legibility
  printf '%s\n' \
          "From: jrpng" \
          "To: tom@gmail.com" \
          "Subject: Test new Bash script" \
          "Mime-Version: 1.0" \
          "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"" \
          "X-Comment: # notice the empty line after this one" \
          "" \
          "--${boundary}" \
          "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"US-ASCII\"" \
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" \
          "Content-Disposition: inline" \
          "X-Comment: # these headers are all superfluous really" \
          "X-Comment: # (default is text/plain us-ascii 7bit inline)" \
          "X-Comment: # but the next empty line is important" \
          "" \
          "The reports are attached to this email as requested" \
          ""

  for file in "${attachments[@]}"; do
      [ ! -f "$file" ] &&
          echo "Attachment $file not found, omitting file"  >&2 && 
          continue
      mimetype=$(get_mimetype "$file")
      printf '%s\n' \
          "--${boundary}" \
          "Content-Type: $mimetype" \
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" \
          "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"" \
          ""
      base64 "$file"
      echo
  done
  printf '%s\n' "--${boundary}--"
} | /usr/lib/sendmail -t -oi
```

Comment: I also dissuade from hard-coding `/usr/lib/sendmail`.  Make sure the correct directory is on the `PATH` at the beginning of the script instead.  That way, a user of this script can easily test this without actually sending email by putting their own mock `sendmail` earlier in their private `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks tripleee, as stated new to bash scripting and am generating the script from another language. At the "\"s required, have only ever used them as escape characters in PHP?

Comment: It's just to split a long logical line over many physical lines for legibility. In some ways, a here document would be more elegant. But again, using an existing solution like `mutt` or `mailx` would be a lot more elegant still,

Comment: Okay have that working, but am now failing to add CC and BCC recipients to the email. Actually thinking about it, my message body is showing the default ... something screwed in my script generator.

Comment: `Cc:` and `Bcc:` go right next to `To:` (header order is generally unimportant) so it should not be hard. What does "showing the default" mean?